# Showing referenced node in view

Tags: 7, nodes, views

I have a content type "Project" and a content type "Document". Using the "references" module, the "Document" content type relates to the "Project" content type.

I have a simple view that shows a list of all projects like so:

- Project A
- Project B
- Project C

However, I want the related documents to show up in the list (the relation occurs from the document to the project, not the other way around):

- Project A

  - Document J
  - Document K
- Project B

  - Document L
- Project C

  - Document M
  - Document N
  - Document O

I've looked at the eva module (seems to be the wrong tool for the job, but that may just be my inexperience with it.) I've tried using the built in "relationships" with views, but can't find if it's possible that way.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without installing module , simply you will use aggregation and group by Project .

Here is a great tutorial from [nodeone.se](http://nodeone.se/en/the-aggregation-setting-the-emmajane-episode) of how to use agregation in drupal 7
See also this [blog post](http://nodeone.se/en/blog/using-aggregation-in-views) , in the left image he is Grouping by the room(nodereference)